# How to make TypeScript type key based on its value property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

I want to create type that takes type of an indexable object with values
(for example this one:)

```
const ENUMLIKE_WITH_METADATA = {
    a: {
        position: 1,
        value: 'str',
    },
    b: {
        position: 2,
        value: 'ng',
    },
} as const;
```

and based on this return object with `value` property as object key and position as a value.
Example:

```
type transformedObject = {
    str: 1,
    ng: 2,
}
```

the base object is always following this structure

```
type EnumlikeWithMetadata = {
    [x: string]: {
        value: string;
        position: number;
    };
};
```

what I achieved so far was 2 types, both not working in its own way:

first one matches `value` properties to union type made from all `position` properties:

```
type IntegerEnumlikeHelper<T extends EnumlikeWithMetadata> = {
    [J in T[keyof T]['value']]: T[keyof T]['position']
};
```

the result looks like this:

```
type H = {
  str: 2 | 1;
  ng: 2 | 1;
}
```

second ones maps value to position, but makes it nested into original key

```
type IntegerEnumlikeHelper<T extends EnumlikeWithMetadata> = {
    [C in keyof T]: { [J in T[C]['value']]: T[C]['position'] };
};

type H = {
    readonly a: {
        str: 1;
    };
    readonly b: {
        ng: 2;
    };
}
```

What is the correct way to map nested values as key and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) using the syntax `{[A in B as K]: V}`:

```
type Transform<T extends Record<keyof T, { position: any, value: PropertyKey }>> =
    { -readonly [K in keyof T as T[K]['value']]: T[K]['position'] }
```

Here I'm requiring that the transformed type `T` has to have property values with a `position` property and a `value` property, and furthermore that the `value` property must be key-like.  Then we iterate through each `K` in `keyof T` and produce the key-value pairs.  The desired key is `T[K]['value']` (the type of the `value` property for the `K`-keyed property of `T`), and the desired value is `T[K]['position']`.

Let's verify that it works:

```
type TransformedObject = Transform<typeof ENUMLIKE_WITH_METADATA>
/* type TransformedObject = {
    str: 1;
    ng: 2;
}*/
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogOQKoFkAyBJA0nA+gdQwBUAJXFOIgQQBErqYBeGAbwCgZOYBDALlY5chABxAQAllHHh+ARgA0goZwBu3ADYBXAKb8A5NABOexUIC+prgCN+7ZV1ESpMmACZL9tVt0w9YAOYmSjAWbGY8EDCgkFAA3GwJUACewtowNNoShtoAJkSG3JAAZiCGALa5APJWAFbawLDMdlxGch4wAfzuYYkpafmFECXlADxEMNoAHlDaYDmRAEr1pTkjANbaSSBFMETyrDCOktJg-IVJ+146-AAKhiCphslYmyEAfG9MwSwwALTZ3By4HUSRgAG0sDBxGAYBstjtxtxIkQIQBdMF6K7aPSo1H8FFYdF6I7OMA4kK9VK7ArFUoVHLVOoNJjUwbDMojZKpbbwZDobB4QikciUWj0KhvNgAegAVDAuf0aUM6VVavVGgIhK0YLJ4kJOm54mYZVKgA)